# Two out of Three variable values in if statement One required plus one or both of the others

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have been working on an old app mostly dealing with upgrading from mysql to mysqli and removing depreciated functions. While debugging the mess I would occasionally have an error with in line hyperlink to edit or delete products. Examples

`php?act=del&cat_id=5&bc=654321&ds=&src=app`

`php?act=del&cat_id=5&bc=&ds=ds12345&src=app`

`php?act=del&cat_id=5&bc=654321&ds=ds12345&src=app`

Some had one part some had two
But then discovered that items in a category could have 2 different identifiers ‘ds’ or ‘bc’ or both and the links to edit or delete these items could have one or the other or both neither. Or could have different errors! This Code is what they pointed to.

```
// Original code
if ($_GET['act'] == 'del') {
  $cat_id = $_GET['cat_id'];
  $ds = $_GET['ds'];
  $bc = $_GET['bc'];

  if($cat_id == '' && $ds == '' || $bc == '') {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action!';
  }
  else {
  //$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_pwd, $db_name);
  // Do some SQL Stuff in cat_id that match ds or bc
}
```

I tried dozens of variations of the original 
`if($cat_id == '' && $ds == '' || $bc == '')`
using || && equal to or not equal to and one way or another could never get one to be correct in all cases. Including the one suggested by trincot

`if ($cat_id == '' &&  ($ds == '' || $bc == '' ))`

Which works for most cases but allows db connect with ds=’’ and bc =’’

The code below I wrote works as needed for all cases of bad query strings But what I was hoping is someone might have a better way to do it.

```
// From GET -- Just to fix if($cat_id == '' && $ds == '' || $bc == '') {

$cat_id = 3;
$ds = 'bbb';
$bc = '';
// define some vars
$c = 'NO'; $d = 0; $b = 0; $t = 0; $s = 0;
if (is_numeric($cat_id))  {
    $c = 'OK'; }
if ($ds != '') {
    $d = 1;
}
if ($bc != '') {
    $b = 1;
}
$t = $d + $b;
if ( $s == $t || $c != 'OK') {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action! ';
    }
    else {
    echo ' OK two out three aint bad as long as one is cat ';
    //$db = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_login, $db_pwd, $db_name);
    // Do some SQL Stuff in cat_id that match ds or bc
    }
```

This is a working sample of what I came up with Thanks for looking any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd32ad87ff42836660a59f826b8f08fa0f8d16f0

Here are the different examples I want to test against. And desired result I know I need to update other parts of the original code but for now I am just looking for an easier way to trigger My Error! before db connect!

```
example 1:
$cat_id = 3;
$ds = '';
$bc = '';

Result: Error Cannot identify item for action! \\ No Part number either ds or bc

example 2:
$cat_id = 'a';
$ds = 'ds-195062';
$bc = '654321';

Result : Error Cannot identify item for action! \\ wrong cat_id

example 3:
$cat_id = '';
$ds = 'ds-195062';
$bc = '654321';

Result : Error Cannot identify item for action! \\ no cat id

example 4:
$cat_id = '5';
$ds = '';
$bc = '654321';

Result :  OK two out three aint bad as long as one is cat  
\\ have a bc part number and a catagory

example 5:
$cat_id = '5';
$ds = 'ds-195062';
$bc = '654321';

Result :  OK two out three aint bad as long as one is cat  
\\ have a bc and ds part number and a catagory

example 6:
$cat_id = '5';
$ds = 'ds-195062';
$bc = '';

Result :  OK two out three aint bad as long as one is cat  
\\ have a ds part number and a catagory
```

This is an edit to the original question hoping it is more clear now

Thank You for looking

Ended up with this Thanks @trincot for explaining this to me

```
if ($_GET['act'] == 'del') {
  $cat_id = ( isset( $_GET['cat_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['cat_id'] ) ) ? intval( $_GET['cat_id'] ) : 0;
  $ds = isset($_GET['ds']) ? $_GET['ds'] : '';
  $bc = isset($_GET['bc']) ? $_GET['bc'] : '';  
  if ( $ds == '' ) { $ds = 'n'; }
  if ( $bc == '' ) { $bc = 'n'; }

  if($cat_id == 0 || ($ds == 'n' && $bc == 'n')) {

    echo 'Error! ';
    echo 'Result: value of ds ' . $ds .' value of bc '. $bc .' cat id is '. $cat_id;
  }
  else {
    echo 'Good To Go ';
    echo 'Result: value of ds ' . $ds .' value of bc '. $bc .' cat id is '. $cat_id; 
  }
}
```

Comment: What you are trying to achieve ? I still can't figure out.

Comment: If cat_id OK and ds null or bc null error 
if ds ok bc ok but cat_id not error
If cat_id OK and ds ok but bc null good to go to SQL
If cat_id OK and ds null but bc ok good to go to SQL
if all are ok good to go to SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the `&&` and `||` operators in the wrong sense. Change this:

```
if($cat_id == '' && $ds == '' || $bc == '') {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action!';
}
```

to this:

```
if($cat_id == '' || ($ds == '' && $bc == '')) {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action!';
}
```

Note that the extra parentheses are not needed because `&&` has precedence over `||`, but it does not hurt to be clear.

Also, unless your `else` block contains all other code, you need to exit the script execution when this error occurs (maybe after doing some other handling first):

```
if($cat_id == '' || ($ds == '' && $bc == '')) {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action!';
    // Some other handling/rendering could come here, but then exit:
    exit();     
}
```

Now, the variables will not be `''` when the parameters are not passed at all. It would be good to cover for that as well (***edit:*** and the numeric check which you had only in the second code block), and first do:

```
$cat_id = (isset($_GET['cat_id']) && is_numeric($cat_id)) ? $_GET['cat_id'] : '';
$ds = isset($_GET['ds']) ? $_GET['ds'] : '';
$bc = isset($_GET['bc']) ? $_GET['bc'] : '';
// ... and then:
if($cat_id == '' || ($ds == '' && $bc == '')) {
    echo 'Error Cannot identify item for action!';
    // Some other handling/rendering could come here, but then exit:
    exit();     
}
```

Comment: Thought i tried that......... But that will work provided I validate  the cat_id first and i was already planning on using isset I must have messed something else up when i tried parentheses your way and didn't get desired result all good Thank You

Comment: I think this will work just fine to  validate the cat_id as at least numeric 
`  $cat_id = (isset( $_GET['cat_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_GET['cat_id'] )) ? $_GET['cat_id'] : '';`

Thanks again @trincot

Comment: I did try that........ Problem is if both ds and bc are not passed it will not trigger the error that's why i skipped it. I would rather have my error than an SQL error so I will keep looking for a solution. @trincot

Comment: It should generate the error (the `if` condition is clear on that), but don't forget to exit. I updated my answer with that. NB/ It is not nice to add the code I posted here in your question. Now it looks really stupid that I even answered.

Comment: No even with the isset It will skip the error if there is no value in ds and bc thats why I came up with that mess I did 

example url to test
test.php?act=del&cat_id=2&ds=&bs=&src=app

It shouldnt happen but I want to make sure and yes i would probably redirect then exit on the error

Comment: Could you do a `var_dump( $_GET['ds'] )` and see what you get as output? This way of debugging should help you identify what value you need to test for. Normally it should be `""`, but maybe you have something else going on.

Comment: test.php:31:string '' (length=0)

Comment: So that is indeed an empty string. So `$ds` cannot be anything else than an empty string. If the same is true for `$bc`, then also that string is empty. When I execute the `if` with those values, it gets to the `echo`. So please also `var_dump` the values of `$ds` and `$bc`...etc... it is matter of debugging.

Comment: The problem is that I do not have access to all the pages that may actually call this `if ($_GET['act'] == 'del')` to delete items otherwise the thing to do would be to fix all them but they are mixed with random pages on a static site and also from 2 other sites as well. The solution I came up with will call an error before db connect is even open as i will have to do something similar for other functions like del cat or edit item etc. I could also validate ds and bc more than just `!= ''` Just looking for additional ideas before i move forward. Thanks

Comment: This is quite vague *"they are mixed with random pages on a static site and also from 2 other sites as well"*. I am afraid I cannot help you with random pages ;-) Whatever solution, you should of course apply it before things get "random" and other pages are included to which you have no access. What more validation do you need for `$bc` and `$bc`? There is nothing about that in your question? I have no idea what you expect us to contribute.

Comment: The second block of code in the question "This is what I came up with it works but there has to be a better way!" validates The If statement just to be error if both are missing I could further validate ds as ds part numbers are only ds-325456 or ds290960 or 0616-0075 or 20010631 bc numbers are even easier to validate

Comment: And, you know how to do that? Like `if (!in_array($ds, ['ds-325456', 'ds290960', '0616-0075', '20010631'])) { die 'bad or missing ds'; }`. Repeat same logic for `$bc`. But if you have more questions about this, please ask a new question. The original question has been answered, in my view.

Comment: Yes i guess there is not a better way I will probably use 
`if (preg_match($ds, \REGEX\)) { ` \\ match part numbers used for both ds and bc to define a value of d and b and use that to start db connect

Thanks for your help

Comment: OK sorry Thanks for your hel

Comment: Thanks again just made a slight variation of your answer and all is good marked the question as answered updated question @trincot

Comment: Thanks, just note that you don't need `else { $ds = $_GET['ds']; }` in your code, as it will already have that value. Secondly, it is not necessary that you put an answer inside your question. It should remain a question. In general: if you believe you have an answer to your own question that is not given in any of the answers, then you can post an answer to your own question. Just for info.

Comment: Will keep that in mind as I am still getting schooled on Stack etiquette Thanks again